# Telnet IAC commands

Tags: linux, command-line, telnet

I want to turn off character echoing in Telnet via linux command line by sending

```
IAC DON'T ECHO
```

command. I have been searching everywhere, and I couldn't find how to to do.
Basically, I don't know how to send `IAC` commands in Telnet linux command line interface.

Answer (score 1):

Enter telnet command mode (press current escape character, `C-]` by default) while connected to remote host, and run `send dont echo` command, then exit command mode.